# React-Native: Cant find component variable.

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

I am trying to setup navigation system. Using [react navigation api](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) but having this, "Cant find component variable. " problem. What I did is...

*App.js*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import WelcomeScreen from './src/screens/Welcome';
import DashboardScreen from './src/screens/Dashboard';

const appSwitchNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
  Welcome:{ screen: WelcomeScreen },
  Dashboard:{ screen: DashboardScreen }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(appSwitchNavigation);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer/>
  }
}

export default App
```

*Welcome.js*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";

export default class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
});
```

Anyone know why I am facing with this error? 
And this is the file structure:
[image]

Comment: What is your exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to import **Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Correct Code:

**App.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import WelcomeScreen from './src/screens/Welcome';
import DashboardScreen from './src/screens/Dashboard';

const appSwitchNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
  Welcome:{ screen: WelcomeScreen },
  Dashboard:{ screen: DashboardScreen }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(appSwitchNavigation);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer/>
  }
}

export default App
```

**WelcomeScreen.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";

export default class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
});
```

Comment: thank you, I forgot to add component and I fixed that, but now I am getting this error.  "Super expression must be either null or function." any idea about this?

Comment: You can accept the answer as well. I will try to run the code and will check if got an issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems Component  import from 'react' is missing in App.js and Welcome.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

Or you can use:

```
class App extends React.Component
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that problem but now I having this error. "Super expression must be either null or function."  I updated the question. Could you check it out again?